# Is there a valid address that can never be assigned?

Tags: address

I seem to remember reading that there is a contract or user address slot that can never be assigned when an account is created, which makes it a useful placeholder or dummy address in contract development.

Can someone please remind me what this is and/or link me to where I can find a list of these addresses?

Or alternatively let me know if I am hallucinating. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean [tz1Ke2h7sDdakHJQh8WX4Z372du1KChsksyU](https://tzkt.io/tz1Ke2h7sDdakHJQh8WX4Z372du1KChsksyU/operations/)? It's called the null address because it's internally a list of zeros (that yields tz1Ke2... when encoded as a base-58 public key hash).

And with current "mainstream" computers, one cannot (easily) compute the corresponding private key.

Comment: I don't think so... I seem to remember there was an address that is 'set aside' so it doesn't have an associated account if you look it up on an explorer, but it also will never be issued. But it is possible I am misremembering or confused. What is the difference between the null address and the burn address: tz1burnburnburnburnburnburnburjAYjjX? Or are they the same?

Comment: I'd say they are the same. The null address is just made of a list of zeros before being encoded. And for me, any address (including tz1Ke2 and tz1burn) could actually be spent if one manages to guess their corresponding private key. But, we make the hypothesis that one cannot do that (at least currently).